# K String Turing machine

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, turing-machines

Given any $k$-string Turing machine $M$ operating within time $f(n)$, we can construct a single-string Turing machine $M$ operating within time $O(f(n)^2)$ such that for any input $x$, $M(x)=M(x)$

How can we prove that converse is false?

Answer (score 1):

Just take $k=1$ and use the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).